# Need to customize (Add Button or Combo box) in Modern View strap of SharePoint 2019 using ASP.NET

Tags: sharepoint-addin

**Priority: High**

**Environment**:

OS: Windows Server 2019

SharePoint: - Version 2019

Development Language: - asp.net

Deploy File: wsp

.

**Requirement**: - We are developing an Add-On on Sharepoint 2019, for “Document Library” and “List” which is working fine and creates a button on “settings” to open a site and perform operation further, but in classic view only. Button is coming from following Elements.xml

[image]

It is not working on “Modern View”, we have tried to search on internet, but not able to find suitable article which can suggest/assist to create “Tabs/Combo box” in Modern view.

[image]
.

I will really thankful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ListView Command Set extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api). With [SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) you can customize more facets of the SharePoint experience, including notification areas, toolbars, and list data views.

[image]

Details can be found [in this Microsoft knowledge article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Let me add that SharePoint is on-premises, not online. Kindly assist in ASP.Net.

Comment: I believe this would work in on-premises as well. Unfortunately I am not aware of any possible solution using ASP.NET. Microsoft is moving towards a uniform experience in SharePoint on-line and on-premises versions and I have seen the trend is to move away from server side deployments. If there are no blockers at your environment then please check the feasibility of this solution.